# tweepy verifier runtime error

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to run a simple app using twitter API wraper called tweepy (with Python), and I can't get past the verifier step.

My code is really simple.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import flask 
import tweepy

session=dict()
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

try:
    redirect_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
    session['request_token']=(auth.request_token.key, auth.request_token.secret)
except tweepy.TweepError:
    print 'Error! Failed to get request token.'

verifier = request.GET.get('oauth_verifier')
```

It really is the code provided by tweepy documentation, but for some reason, it keeps returning a runtime error.

```
Runtime Error: working outside of request context
```

Anyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing the script show that the error happens on `verifier = request.GET.get('oauth_verifier')`, and googling for the error message shows this error is related to Flask.

So I guess Flask just doesn’t like using `request.GET.get` outside a function called by Flask (which could be what they call a “request context”).
Basically, you should execute the last line only somewhere it makes sense to display data (a web server can only display data if there is a web browser waiting for a response…)

Comment: I think I don't really understand how the verifier works. On tweepy's documentation, it says "If this is a desktop application (or any application not using callbacks) we must query the user for the “verifier code” that twitter will supply them after they authorize us. [...] # Example using callback (web app) verifier = request.GET.get('oauth_verifier')"To make my purpose clear, my app doesn't have any other intention than retrieving data from twitter, so how should I use the verifier then ? The line above doesn't work better than what is provided earlier.

Comment: If you are using Flask, it means you are not writing a desktop application but a web application